# how to open up .sh extension in ubuntu

Tags: linux

I am a window user,and never tried Linux before. Because of project, I installed the Ubuntu and I downloaded one file in .sh extension. That file is the python from Enthough Distribution. I tried to double clicked the .sh file and there is error. I really have no idea how Linux works. I searched in Google but they showed some command lines that I don't understand. So I hope somebody can provide some detailed guide. Sorry I am a total Linux newbie.

Here is a picture of the error:
[image]

Comment: Get familiar with http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you want to run it or edit it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just open a terminal (should be somewhere in your application menu), go to the directory where the `.sh` file is (command is `cd /the/path` then `Enter`) and type:

```
sh yourfile.sh
```

or

```
./yourfile.sh
```

then `Enter`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to change permissions of that file unless you have done already.

- In ubuntu terminal type: `sudo -i`. Now, you're root!
- Go to the folder with this file (`cd` command).
- Do `man chmod` command (change file mode bits). Check permissions of that file:

  root:/folder_with_sh_file# ls -l | grep 'filename'

If the file is not executable(x), you will have to run this command:

```
root:/folder_with_sh_file# chmod 755 ./filename.sh
```

NB: you can also use 777. 4 - read, 2 - write, 1 - execute. If you SUM together, it all works out.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open it normally with gedit all it is is text its not a binary or anything the only reason I can think of would be if that wasnt the actual file type I'd be wary of using that. .sh is well you could say the equivalent of .bat on windows its pure text so it should open normally that is unless its a binary,picture,or mp3.

Comment: chmod +x will make it executable

Answer (score 0):

use `vim 'filename'` for opening the file to read/modify it in a cli (command line interface / shell) or use `gedit 'filename'` to read/modify it in a graphical interface.

if you have no permissions to do so, checkout `man chowner` to change the onwer of the file and `man chmod` for file permissions. You might need to use `sudo 'command'` in some cases, the `sudo` command allows you to run programs with the security privileges of another user (normally the superuser, or root).

Check this link out to get some really basic linux knowledge: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting

Answer (score 0):

If no permissoin issues then use this in terminal :

```
Run bash <filename>.sh
```

else if permission issues are there then follow this :

Give execute permission to your script:

```
chmod +x /path/to/filename.sh
```

And to run your file:

```
/path/to/filename.sh
```

Since . refers to the current directory: if filename.sh is in the current directory, you can simplify this to:

```
./filename.sh
```